# Getting Friends' status updates in Android Facebook SDK

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm developing a facebook app on Android that gets some of the user's friends' status updates and then categorizes them based on keywords in the status. However, I'm having a very hard time trying to find how out how to get a list of the user's friends' status updates.

So far, I have the code to get the user's friends from the graph API, but I don't believe that includes the friends' statuses. Here's the code I've written:

```
private void categorizeFriends(final Session session){

    //get friend data
    Request request = Request.newMyFriendsRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserListCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(List<GraphUser> users, Response response){

            if(response.getError() != null && session == Session.getActiveSession()){
                for(GraphUser u : users){
                    categorizeFriend(u);
                }
            }
        }
    });

    request.executeAsync();

}
```

In this code, the categorizeFriend method is going to get the friends' status updates and put them in a global ArrayList depending on what they get categorized as. However, it look like the GraphUser doesn't have any status information in it--it just returns each friend's general information.

So I have two parts to this question:

1) Is there a way to hit two birds with one stone and do this in one request instead of having to do another request in categorizeFriend?

2) What would a request look like to get the user's friends' statuses? I've seen that I can set the parameters for the request and then execute it, but how would I collect the user's statuses after executing that request?

Thank you for helping me--I've been looking all over and haven't been able to find a good answer for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you are aware that the `friends_*` permissions will vanish on April 30th 2015 (and you can therefore no longer use the Graph API as you do now), you could use Field Expansion to get all friend's statuses with on request:

```
GET /me?fields=friends.fields(statuses.limit(5))
```

This will return the last 5 status updates of the user's (of the access token used with this query) friends.

I strongly recommend that you restrict the fields of the statuses as well, otherwise it's likely that the query takes too  much execution time and Facbook will cancel the query (it will return "request failed").

References:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_permissions
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.0#fieldexpansion

Answer (score -1):

You will need to create a request for each friend's feed, but you can execute them with RequestBatch.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/RequestBatch/

This sends all requests and collects the results in a single trip to the facebook server. This page has important information under limits. Each request in the batch will count towards the API usage limit rather than the batch counting as one. It also says the batch limit is 50 requests in one batch.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/making-multiple-requests

Sorry to say that I don't have any example code for you, but this page does:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/graph

I can't link you directly to the code, but the first list states "Using batch requests to make your app more efficient." Just follow the links to get to the code. Hope this helps.